# Android Ice Cream Sandwich: why ListView items remain selected by default?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm experiencing a weird and apparently undocumented issue on Android ICS. This is the xml code of my listview:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/cell_selected_small"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants" />
```

On Android 2.2 (tested on multiple devices) the listview selection is cleared right after the touch on it ends. I think this is the correct behavior.

On Android 4.0 and above, the listview selection stays selected, even if the `onListItemClick()` pushes a new Activity on the stack and then the back button is pressed. If then I scroll the listview for a while, the selection disappears after an apparently random amount of time.

Did any of you experience the same issue? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting the same thing.  Can not get it to stop and make the item imposible to see black on black.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a weird issue...set one property of your listview to get through this.

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

Hope this will help you out..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirly sure but I set targert_sdk in my manifest back to 10 and things are OK so I went and looked at the [compatibilty](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) stuff in the documnetation.  The API 11 list inclueds the line.

• GridView and ListView will use View.setActivated for selected items if they do not implement Checkable.

Whish I think is the relervant.  I had

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
```

in my xml and changed it to

```
android:choiceMode="none"
```

This looks to of got things back to what I want.